# Multiple header rows exporting Google Sheets to JSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to export google sheet to JSON formatted text so I can read it into another program. Entries are indexed by multiple headers for the row and columns. I can't share the data as it is not compliant with GDPR, so I have an example below.

E.g.

If I was constructing a table of spells in D&D to determine when they were introduced, I would have the field being School of Magic, the Subfield being the spell down the left column, and then across the header would be indexed by the edition (1 through 5), with sub headed with Base and then name of expansion, each cell is empty or just has a string saying "Yes" if it is present.

Image added to clarify.

[Example table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj1o7.png)

This would then return an entry like this when exported

```
{
"School of Magic":"Necromancy",
"Spell":"Abi-Dalzim's Horrid Wilting",
"Edition":"5th",
"Book":"Elemental Evil Player's Companion"
"Elemental Evil Player's Companion": "Yes"
}
```

I am using this as a base to export
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pamelafox/1878143/raw/6c23f71231ce1fa09be2d515f317ffe70e4b19aa/exportjson.js?utm_source=thenewstack&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=platform

But I am incredibly new to JSON and I can't quite work out how to have multiple headers.

Any help here would be appreciated regarding how to adapt this or even just where to look to solve this sort of problem as I can't find documentation that points me in this direction.

Below is a link to a csv file of a similar table, hopefully I haven't just doxxed myself.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSEHGJgn3x4gpyXfBYqRSoJieiZIoDSbJt_pys_TQM-SzXVJjubJbzOvmUT0cUSRRBYUpkKxPq1IOj_/pub?output=csv

The idea would be that in this example the output would show whenever a given spell was introduced within each edition. So the output would be like:

```
{
"School of Magic":"Necromancy",
"Spell":"Abi-Dalzim's Horrid Wilting",
"Edition":4,
"Book":"Exp2",
"Exp2": "Yes"
"Edition":5,
"Book":"Elemental Evil Player's Companion",
"Elemental Evil Player's Companion": "Yes"
}

{
"School of Magic":"Necromancy",
"Spell":"Raise Undead",
"Edition":1,
"Book":"Base",
"Base": "Yes",
"Edition":2,
"Book":"Base",
"Base": "Yes",
"Edition":3,
"Book":"Base",
"Base": "Yes",
"Edition":4,
"Book":"Base",
"Base": "Yes",
"Edition":5,
"Book":"Base",
"Base": "Yes"
}
```

If this makes sense? In the true data these cells contain information of interactions between the subcolumns so it is important that I can identify which sub columns and what the entry is.

Comment: you wrote `export to a google sheet to JSON` so do you want to export to a google sheet or from a google sheet to json ?

Comment: @MikeSteelson resolved this in the edit. Second one, export google sheet of a structure described with multiple column header rows and multiple columns for row indicators.

Comment: Do you have a example of google sheet?

Comment: @MikeSteelson .CSV file provided of the Google sheet as I couldn't work out how to share it without doxxing myself.

Comment: I asked for a spreadsheet and you answered with a csv! sorry, I didn't find the right values at the right place. Waiting for a spreadsheet. You can use a dummy one https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform

Comment: Sorry @MikeSteelson and thank you for the link.

Provided here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-aGOVsyX-bH-C0vUKrilLEG4KKxmEvs-ZVxACUrohQM/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: I understand why csv was inconsistent, you have so many merged cells! Even so, there are errors for Edition that didn't consider J1 and K1. It will take me some time but I think I will succeed! The test set is also done a little quickly because it does not include all the data replaced by ...

Comment: Whrer is the term 'book' in your data?

Comment: Your final output is not coherent since you can't have same key as 'book' or 'base' with different values!

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson

Thank you for all your help! I think it seems like I will have to go back to the drawing board on this one.

Answer (score 1):

### Try

```
function table2json() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var items = []
  rows.forEach(function(r) {
    var obj={}
    r.forEach(function (c, j) {
      obj[headers[j]] = c
    })
    items.push(obj)
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(items))
}
```

[image]

[image]

### edit

according to your new data and your spreadsheet, try

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()

  // rebuild a complete set
  var temp = ''
  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (i < 2) {
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        if (j > 1) {
          if (c == '') { data[i][j] = temp } else { temp = data[i][j] }
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      if (r[0] == '') { data[i][0] = temp } else { temp = data[i][0] }
    }
  })

  // extract informations
  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (i > 2) {
      var result = []
      if (r[0] == '') { data[i][0] = temp } else { temp = data[i][0] }
      result.push([data[2][0], data[i][0]])
      result.push([data[2][1], data[i][1]])
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        if (j > 2) {
          if (c != '') {
            result.push([data[0][j], data[1][j]])
            result.push(['Book', data[2][j]])
            result.push([data[2][j], data[i][j]])
          }
        }
      })
      console.log((result))
    }
  })
}
```

result

```
[ [ 'School', 'Necromancy' ],
  [ 'Spell', 'Abi-Dalzim\'s...' ],
  [ 'Edition', 4 ],
  [ 'Book', 'Exp2' ],
  [ 'Exp2', 'Yes' ],
  [ 'Edition', 5 ],
  [ 'Book', 'Elemental Evil ...' ],
  [ 'Elemental Evil ...', 'Yes' ] ]

[ [ 'School', 'Necromancy' ],
  [ 'Spell', 'Raise Dead' ],
  [ 'Edition', 2 ],
  [ 'Book', 'Base' ],
  [ 'Base', 'Yes' ],
  [ 'Edition', 3 ],
  [ 'Book', 'Base' ],
  [ 'Base', 'Yes' ],
  [ 'Edition', 4 ],
  [ 'Book', 'Base' ],
  [ 'Base', 'Yes' ],
  [ 'Edition', 5 ],
  [ 'Book', 'Base' ],
  [ 'Base', 'Yes' ] ]
```

Comment: Hi again Mike, I think this is definitely closer to what I was hoping for, but not quite there.

I have now included an image following your screenshot to clear up the structure I mean.

Comment: That doesn't really help me. Can you provide a spreadsheet instead of an image with more complete input (no actual data) and expected output?